# Nested for loop to fill an array with list comprehension

Tags: python, optimization, list-comprehension, nested-loops

Now I have that GUI program that I display an image in and I want to reszze the image so I'm stuck with a nested loop that takes so long.
is there any other method that can be faster like list comprehension? and if so how to do them?

````
for new_x in range(new_width):
     for new_y in range(new_height):
         new_image[new_x,new_y] = image[round(new_x/x_scale),round(new_y/y_scale)] ```
````

Comment: List comprehension is just syntactic sugar which won't provide any performance optimization. You should use some library for faster image operations

Comment: either look into `numpy`, or GPU acceleration

Comment: the point is that I have to do that by hand. It's a task I have to submit so I can't use any library.

Comment: you can try something like `x[::2]` which will only keep every other element. Not sure if you can apply this here

Answer (score 0):

you could use opencv library to resize an image:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.random.randint(0,255,(200,100,3),dtype=np.uint8)

resized_img = cv2.resize(img,dsize = (50,100))
```

Be carefull you need to specify the desired size as (width,height)